# Xcode config file: How to include another config?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

In an Xcode config file, what is the correct way to include another config file by filename?

I have a base Xcode Config and I would like to ensure that the CocoaPods xcode config is included.

Comment: to add another build configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up multiple targets in the project.

These targets use separate .xcconfig files to define the: LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS & OTHER_LDFLAGS for each target.

Or you can add multiple build configurations : [Adding a Build Configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/BasingBuildConfigurationsonConfigurationFiles.html)